# Printing SVG ignores clipPath

Tags: svg, printing, clipping

I'm working on a page to map images to the faces of a hexahexaflexagon (folding paper thingie). To do this I need to crop the images to six triangles in a hexagon, then position those triangles in strips for cutting and folding. I have this working in the browser (tested in recent Firefox, Chrome, and Edge) but when I print it ignores the clipPaths so instead of triangles extracted from the images, it shows the whole original image.

Snapshot of the page is here: https://flexagon-test.glitch.me/
Snapshot of the code: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/flexagon-test?path=js%2Fhexa.js%3A31%3A49

I've tried printing from each of the above printers and I've tried printing to different printers and to PDF and all have the same issue. I'm working on Windows.

I had this working before using canvas, but scaling made the results blurry so I moved it all to SVG, but if I can't print that's a showstopper, since the whole point is to print these.

Thanks in advance for any tips to solve this!

[Update] I tested on a Mac using print to PDF and it had the same problem, so this is not limited to Windows.

Comment: Ah, that pointed me in the right direction, thanks! I was using the print media setting to hide elements that shouldn't be printed, but that was mucking up the print. Instead of not displaying the hidden elements I hid them behind the printable ones, which worked fine in Firefox and Chrome.

In fact, I could probably reorganize the code so the clipPaths are all contained in the displayed SVG and not the hidden one. I hadn't expected hiding the hexagon from printing would remove it from the document altogether, but knowing that, I should be able to fix it. Thanks again!

Comment: There are 3 SVG images inline in the HTML. One is only used to show how an image is clipped to a hexagon and shouldn't be printed, so I was hiding it during printing. Because they are all part of the HTML document, they can share images, clipPaths, etc. The problem was that the clipPaths were defined in the hexagon SVG and when I hid it from printing, it was removed from the document altogether. So by either hiding the hexagon behind the other SVGs (but leaving it in the document) or by moving the clipPath definitions to one of the printable SVGs, I can avoid this issue.